# Blender custom point density from file

Tags: scripting, volumetrics, point-clouds

I'm scoping out solutions for rendering custom volumetric data that I'll be parsing from some external source (a simulation being run externally to Blender). I'd like to use Blender's volumetric rendering capabilities to render frames of simulation output by my program.

Here's an example of rendering some volume (in this case using particles as density markers).

[image]

I'm wondering if it would be possible to put my custom data through the density channel here, through scripting, etc. Maybe there's a way to script the positions of particles in a particle system? Thanks